# regex url matching

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex that matches a url only if after `'/'` there's a dot.

Here's what i've got so far: http://regexr.com/3cu85

my regex is the following: `/facebook.com\/.*[.]/gm`
and i'm testing with this URls:

```
facebook.com
facebook.com/
facebook.com/test.user 

www.facebook.com
www.facebook.com/
www.facebook.com/test.user

https://www.facebook.com
https://www.facebook.com/
https://www.facebook.com/test.user
```

The problem is that I need to match the full url, and as you can it starts from the word "facebook".

I tried different options, but none worked for me.

Thanks for any help

Comment: what should be matched and what should not? Give sample.

Comment: [`(https?:\/\/)?(w{3}\.)?facebook\.com\/[^\/]*\..*`](https://regex101.com/r/oI7mB8/1)?

Comment: basically, everything that has the word facebook.com followed by /{any}.{any} to match only users urls

Comment: brilliant! @WiktorStribiżew that worked exactly like I needed. Thanks a lot

Comment: If anubhava's regex (that I would write as `/\S*\bfacebook\.com\/[^\s.]+\.\S*/`) works for you I will not post my answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew post your answer, i used yours so it is fair that i select your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is

```
(https?:\/\/)?(w{3}\.)?facebook\.com\/[^\/]*\..*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oI7mB8/1) (the `\n` is added to the negated character class `[^\/]` so as to match the URLs on separate lines only, if you test individual strings, the `\n` is not necessary.)

This regex matches:

- `(https?:\/\/)?` - optional (one or zero) occurrence of `http://` or `https://`
- `(w{3}\.)?` - optional (one or zero) occurrence of `www`
- `facebook\.com` - literal sequence `facebook.com`
- `\/` - a literal `/`
- `[^\/]*` - zero or more characters other than `/` (BETTER: use `[^\/.]*` to match any char but a `.` and `/` to avoid redundant backtracking)
- `\.` - a literal `.`
- `.*` - any 0+ characters but a newline (BETTER: since the URL cannot have a space (usually), you can replace it with `\S*` matching zero or more non-whitespace characters).

So, a better alternative:

```
(https?:\/\/)?(w{3}\.)?\bfacebook\.com\/[^\/.]*\.\S*
```

Comment: Another quick one, is it possible to stop it to the first slash? so that if the url is facebook.com/test.user/bla it doesn't match bla?

Comment: Replace the `\S*` / `.*` at the end with `[^\/]*`

Comment: sorry what do i have to replace? only \S*? if so, it is not working properly

Comment: Do you mean to avoid matching the whole URL then? Use [`(https?:\/\/)?(w{3}\.)?\bfacebook\.com\/[^\/.\n]*\.(?![^\/]*\/)\S*`](https://regex101.com/r/oI7mB8/2). I am not sure of your current input, so I am suggesting a lookahead based approach. You could use anchors: [`/^(https?:\/\/)?(w{3}\.)?\bfacebook\.com\/[^\/.]*\.[^\/]*$/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/oI7mB8/3) if you test the strings individually.

Comment: Awesome! that's exactly what i needed :)