# Regex match any url's in string with and without www and create a clickable URL

Tags: php, regex

There are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28193277/php-regex-get-first-url-from-string) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770283/regex-url-matching), but I still have not found a solution to what I try to achieve in php. I `preg_match_all` a string which can contain URLs written in various ways, but also contains text which should not match. What I need to match is:

```
www.something.com 
https://something.com
http://something.com
https://www.something.com
http://www.something.com
```

And any `/..../....` after the URL, but not:

```
www.something.com</p> // this should match everything until the '</p>'
www.something.com. // this should match everything until the '.'
```

So far I got so far is

```
/((http|https)\:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\?\:@\-_=#]+\.([a-zA-Z0-9\&\.\/\?\:@\-_=#])*/
```

and the function

```
if(preg_match_all("/((http|https)\:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\?\:@\-_=#]+\.([a-zA-Z0-9\&\.\/\?\:@\-_=#])*/",$text,$urls)){
    foreach($urls[0]as $url ){
        $text = str_replace($url,'<a href="'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a>',$text);
    }
}
```

but this gives a problem with `http://www....` (the `http://` won't be inlcuded in the displayed text), and with a URL without `http` or `https` the created link is relative to the domain I show the page on. Suggestions?

Here's a live [Demo](https://3v4l.org/VRXuf)

**Edit:** my best regex so for any URL with `http` or `https` is `/(http|https)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})?(\/[A-Za-z0-9-._~!$&()*+,;=:]*)*/`. Now I just need a way to regex the URLs with only `www.something...` and transform that into `http://www.something...` in the `href`.

Here's another [live demo with different examples](https://regex101.com/r/QiPqGP/1).

**Edit 2:** the [answer from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960461/convert-plain-text-urls-into-html-hyperlinks-in-php) is quite good. The only problem with this that I still encounter is with `</p>` after the URL and if there are words before and after a dot (this.for example).

```
$url = '@(http)?(s)?(://)?(([a-zA-Z])([-\w]+\.)+([^\s\.]+[^\s]*)+[^,.\s])@';
$string = preg_replace($url, '<a href="http$2://$4" target="_blank" title="$0">$0</a>', $string);
echo $string;
```

Comment: It is included.

Comment: Please create a live demo to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @revo, did it. See https://3v4l.org/VRXuf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this one fits your needs:

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('~(https?://|www)[a-z\d.-]+[\w/.?=&%:#]*\w~i', function($m) {
    $prefix = stripos($m[0], 'www') === 0 ? 'http://' : '';
    return "<a href='{$prefix}{$m[0]}'>{$m[0]}</a>";
}, $text);
```

Comment: Are you sure? If so, can you publish full text used to test it?

Comment: I also wonder why, I am trying to find out what's wrong, but this is the result:

Comment: <a href="<a href=" http:="" www.something.com'="">http://www.something.com</a>'&gt;www.something.com http://<a href="<a href=" http:="" www.something.com'="">http://www.something.com</a>'&gt;www.something.com https://<a href="<a href=" http:="" www.something.com'="">http://www.something.com</a>'&gt;www.something.com

Comment: I understand what is wrong now, the `$matches` are both the URLs and the prefixes.

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber This is because it replaces same URLs multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

```
$text =  "<p>Some string www.test.com with urls http://test.com in it http://www.test.com. </p>";
$text = preg_replace_callback("@(http)?(s)?(://)?(([a-zA-Z])([-\w]+\.)+([^\s\.]+[^\s]*)+[^,.\s])@", 'replace_callback', $text);

function replace_callback($matches){
    return '<a href="' . $matches[0] . '" target="_blank">' . $matches[0] . '</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You regex was almost correct!

You we're matching a literal dot `\.` followed by 0 or more group of characters including the dot.

So i changed it to matching a literal dot followed by 1 or more characters excluding the dot which seems to be what you want, here is the final regex:

```
((http|https)\:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\?\:@\-_=#]+\.([a-zA-Z0-9\&\/\?\:@\-_=#])+
```

See it in action:
https://regex101.com/r/h5pUvC/3/

Comment: I used your regex, but I still have some problems. I updated the question to make things more clear.

Comment: See also https://regex101.com/r/h5pUvC/4 for an example of another problem I encounter.